# webhook call for speech failed

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I deployed my function at firebase and tried to call webhook in dialogflow but this results

> Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: speech in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.WebhookResponse

This is the Screenshot of code 
[image]

here is the url

https://us-central1-fir-functions2-2c9a5.cloudfunctions.net/webhook
suggestions to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Generally, cutting and pasting in code samples and error messages, rather than including a screenshot, will make it more likely that you'll get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to write `fulfillmentText` instead of speech, since you are using dialogflow v2
Have a look of dialogflow v2 request and response here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this guide from Dialogflow for building webhook endpoints](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook). You'll want to use [the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) to craft responses.

Comment: I've used webhook instead of Inline editor and I found no guide on it so can you help me out of this ?

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@antonyharfield/dialogflow-web-hooks-how-to-develop-locally-and-deploy-to-cloud-functions-48839919e998).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using V2 api of dialogflow as I change it to V1 api it works